# jQuery: How to match one of two variables

Tags: jquery, string, match

I'm currently using jQuery to match options in a drop-down to a string. That's working, no issues. User puts in a string, I strip out unwanted characters and/or abbreviate certain words, then find a matching option in the drop-down. However, I also need to check for the original string.

For example, say a user enters the string "Madison County Hospital". We'll call this *strNameRaw*. After I run it through the process, it becomes "Madison CNTY HSPTL", which we'll call *strNameFixed*. I then use the code below to find a match for the *strNameFixed* value:

```
$("select[title='Project Name'] option").filter(function() { return $(this).text() === strNameFixed }).prop('selected', true);
```

I've done a few google searches, but so far I haven't found a way to search for either string. I want a result of TRUE or "1" if either one is matched, not just the one I've processed.

**How can I re-write this line so that it searches for EITHER string instead of just one?**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly. You just need to match either and select first.

```
$("select[title='Project Name'] option")
       .filter(function() { 
           var txt = $(this).text();
           return txt === strNameFixed || txt === strNameRaw
       })
       .first()
       .prop('selected', true);
```